# RestEasy service deploy in Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, tomcat7, resteasy

I'm developing a Rest service with RestEasy. I need to deploy in Tomcat. And I think that I have problems in my web.xml

This is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyServices</display-name> 
    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/services</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.service.services.MessageApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have a service:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String Hello(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        return("Hello "+name);
    }
```

And when I deploy, and I call to `http://localhost:8080/MyServices/services/hello?name=Jesus`
Tomcat shows this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I include `resteasy-cache-core-3.0.6.Final, resteasy-jackson-provider-3.0.6.Final, resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final, resteasy-oauth-3.0.6.Final, resteasy-servlet-initializer-3.0.6.Final and resteasy-validator-provider-11-3.0.6.Final` I have the next error in deploy time:

```
dic 24, 2013 4:04:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Grave: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I don't know what is my problem. Do I need to import any jar into WEB-INF/lib?? What jar??
What have I done wrong?
I don't know if I'm calling in the correct way to my service. Also, I don't know why tomcat don't run.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the [resteasy library](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.6.Final/resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar) into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

You can download them from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/

If you use Maven you find the dependencies here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/

Comment: What resteasy libreries?? Because when I include resteasy libraries, Tomcat show me other error (see the question edited)

Comment: do you use maven for your dependencies and what other errors are shown?

Comment: I don't use maven or ants. It is a simple Rest service :(. And I downloaded RestEasy complete from http://www.jboss.org/resteasy

Comment: Ok then include http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.6.Final/resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar into your wars WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: why do you include all the libs besides resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final? Do you need them for parts of your application? Did you follow a tutorial? If so, could you point me to its URL?

Comment: No, at first, I don't add in WEB-INF/lib. Then I tried to add some jars. And when you say me that I need to add resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final, I added only. But Tomcat shows an error when it starts.

Comment: There are some examples on github. This in particular looks quite simple. https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/examples/examples-jsapi .It uses maven though, but this shouldn't be an issue if you manually include the resteasy-jaxrs war. Try to follow this example. Also, check your war. Unzip it and see if you have really included the resteasy jar in the right place.