# Jersey Services with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

I'm developing a rest service with Jersey 2.0 (I downloaded from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.5/jaxrs-ri-2.5.zip) and I'm using Tomcat 7.0.47. I run Tomcat from Eclipse and my machine is a Mac.

I'm using the Eclipse tool to generate a WAR and to deploy the service.

This is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyServices</display-name> 
    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.service.services.Services</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I include all Jersey jars into WEB-INF/lib, except `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` that it is into Apache/lib
When I deploy in Tomcat, it shows a very strange error caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you have understood ClassNotFoundExceptions? I'm asking because you had a similar question lately... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762707/resteasy-service-deploy-in-tomcat-7-0-47

Comment: Hehehe, of course, my friend. I have the same problems that with Resteasy.

Comment: And of course, I do the same: include libraries in web-inf/lib, etc

Comment: Ok, then maybe you want to have a look at http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html. This is tomcat + javaee libs on top. Take a look particularily at the JAX-RS version. http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Does it work under Mac?? Oh, I need to use Tomcat, because it's part of a project that is using Tomcat :(

Comment: yes, its java, it runs on a mac. ok, then how do you package your war file? maven? ant? by hand?

Comment: By hand, with the Eclipse export tool. I export to war automatically

Comment: Then pls extract the war file and tell me what is inside the wars Web-Inf lib folder. I assume you didn't package the war correctly

Comment: Only META-INF and WEB-INF folder

Comment: ok, there you have your problem. Your libs have to be inside the WEB-INF/lib folder. Revisit your packageing steps. Somehow you miss to include the required libs. Make sure you understand what has to go inside a war if you package it manually, otherwise follow the answer of Nicholas Karl. Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution:

1. Add into Tomcat/lib all libraries that you download from Jersey and
   are including into `/ext` folder of the Jersey .zip
2. Add into Web-Inf/lib of my project only libraries that are under `/lib` folder of the Jersey zip file
3. Add into Web-Inf/lib of my project `javax.ws.rs-api-2.jar` that you can find in `/api` folder of Jersey

With this, I don't have problems to run Tomcat with Jersey.

And this is my web.xml for `Jersey 2.0`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyRESTServices</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.myservice.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Where `com.myservice.services` is the package where I have my services

Thanks for your comments!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the jars in the `/ext` folder, I missed those at first. And of course the servlet mapping piece is quite important and not mentioned in the Jersey getting started guide either.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on a PC. Did you make the eclipse project a maven project? If you do that then you can use org.glassfish.jersey.bundles jaxrs-ri version 2.5 (or whichever) as a dependency in your pom and then when you do run->maven-install from eclipse it will build a war file with all the necessary dependencies in it.

Comment: I don't use maven. And it is a requeriment of the project to use Tomcat :(

Comment: I am using the m2e (maven to eclipse) plugin for eclipse. This is what gives me maven in eclipse. You should use that.

Comment: But is it necessary to use maven to generate a war file?

Comment: Well, that depends on whether or not you want to.

Comment: At this moment I prefer not include maven in the project. I know maven, but I don't want to use

Answer (score 0):

Adding Jersey to an Eclipse project without maven is simple: Click properties for the project, go to the Java Build Path. Click on the Add Library on the left, select user library. After you click next you will see "user libraries" in the upper right. Click that. Click new. Add a name: jaxrs-ri-2.5 for example. Click add external jars, and add the jars in the api, lib and ext folders. You're done. This will probably also include them in any war file you make with eclipse.

Worked for me.

Comment: No, before I put my question here, I did all these steps and it didn't work. I had to put the libraries in the way that I put in my own answare.

Answer (score -1):

Go with jdk1.7.0_04 and install apache-tomcat-7.0.55 and set the environment variable for this setting and set eclipse for same for compiling building and runtime. then everything will be OK for Jax-RS-2.1