# How can I configure a RESTful service using Jersey 2.7 and Jackson 2.0 under Tomcat

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, tomcat8

I´ve been developing a RESTful to understand and learn abaout Jersey, Jackson and Hibernate.
I spent a big amout of time trying fix this problem and I think all is ok. But when I try to run the application under Apache Tomcat 8 the error below is raised:

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
 javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
[2014-04-11 10:32:26,913] Artifact company-app:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/company-app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    ... 31 more
```

**This is `web.xml` under 2.5 version:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             version="2.5">
        <display-name>company-app</display-name>
        <!-- Jersey servlet Configuration -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>app-servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.company.resources</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.company.configuration.RestApp</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>app-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>hotel-application.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <!-- Jersey servlet Configuration -->

    </web-app>
```

**This is implementation of the JacksonFeature to enable JSON convertion:**

```java
    package com.company.features;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;


    public class JacksonFeature implements Feature {

        public boolean configure( final FeatureContext context ) {

            String postfix = '.' + context.getConfiguration().getRuntimeType().name().toLowerCase();

            context.property( CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + postfix, true );

            context.register( JsonParseExceptionMapper.class );
            context.register( JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class );
            context.register( JacksonJsonProvider.class, MessageBodyReader.class, MessageBodyWriter.class );

            return true;
        }

    }
```

**This is implementation of the `RestApp` class:**

```java
    package com.company.configuration;

    import com.company.features.JacksonFeature;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

    //@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/service/*")
    public class RestApp extends ResourceConfig {
        public RestApp() {
            register(new GZipEncoder());
            register(JacksonFeature.class);
            //packages("com.company.resources");
        }
    }
```

**And these are the dependencies that are in use by application on the `pom.xml`:**

```xml
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
```

Any thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with you, but I solved it just now.

1. download [Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), and unzip
2. copy all files under `lib/` and `api/` to your `WEB-INF/lib`
3. **AND THE MOST IMPORTANT!!!** copy all files under `ext/` to your tomcat's `lib/` folder (i.e. `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib` on my Ubuntu)

*refers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784531/jersey-services-with-tomcat-and-eclipse)*