# Unable to create simple java restapi in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, http-status-code-404, classnotfoundexception, tomcat8.5

I am following this link for creating a simple Java restApi in Eclipse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQSat1cKMo.

However, I am getting a 404 response and console reports an error of

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class`

It's a dynamic web project and web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <display-name>JavaAPI</display-name>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>JAVA_API</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>test</param-value>
   </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>JAVA_API</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

The Hello.java is :

```
package test;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayHello() {
    String resource = "<? xml version='1.0' ?>" +
"<hello> Hi eesh, hello from xml</hello>";
    return resource;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayHelloJASON() {
    String resource = null;
    return resource;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHelloHTML() {
    String resource = "<h1> hi eesh, from html</h1>";
    return resource;
}
}
```

The tomcat version is 8.5, jax-rs-2.25..

localhost:8080 doesn't show the apache home page in the chrome browser and on executing the program on the tomcat server...I get the below response..

[image]

I have referred this issue in other links:

[org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception#22023981)
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco)
[Jersey Services with Tomcat and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784531/jersey-services-with-tomcat-and-eclipse)

I have tried most of the solutions and none of them seem to work. Moreover, I wanted to do this without converting it to a maven project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: my recommendation: don't follow youtube tutorials. there are enough step by step tutorials online, that don't put a time-limit on going through it. Here are a few
https://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/ 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`servlet-class` should contain a fully qualified **class name**. The `.class` extension is just part of the on-disk **file name**, and not part of the **class name**. Remove it.

Comment: This worked but the problem is that the html part of the code is executed first and not the xml part whilst in the tutorial its the other way around.